# What is the radial dependence of the density of Jupiter or Saturn?

Tags: planet, jupiter, saturn

Can anyone point me to the reference where I can find the density of Jupiter or Saturn as a function of the distance from its center?

Comment: I think the best that science has to offer will be a variety of different theoretical predictions based on various assumptions and models. The problem is that the actual material composition as a function isn't known, and even if it were the behavior of materials at these pressures is usually only theoretical.

Comment: Highly relevant and contains an answer for Jupiter https://astronomy.stackexchange.com/questions/28882/gravitational-acceleration-inside-a-planet/28886?r=SearchResults#28886